Promise.all immediately jumps to then instead of calling all promises
I'm new to promises and trying to get Promises.all to work in this situation.  However, when I try to run the code by calling the processFiles function, it just immediately hits the console.log line in the Promises.all then method.  What am I doing wrong?
let doc1Text = "";
let doc2Text = "";

const processDoc = async (fileInput) => {
    var input = document.getElementById(fileInput);
    
    await fetch(urls.GetContractLanguageText, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: input.files[0]
    })
    .then(j => j.json())
    .then(x => {                    
        return x.ConvertedText;
    });
}

const processDoc1 = async () => {
    $(selectors.fileProgress1).val(0);
    doc1Text = await processDoc(selectors.baseFile);
    $(selectors.fileProgress1).val(100);
};

const processDoc2 = async () =>  {
    $(selectors.fileProgress2).val(0);
    doc1Text = await processDoc(selectors.newFile);
    $(selectors.fileProgress2).val(100);
};

const processFiles = async () => {
    $(selectors.aiComparison).removeClass(selectors.hide);
    await Promise.all([processDoc1, processDoc2])
        .then(() => {
          console.log(doc1Text, doc2Text);
        });
}


You don't combine await with then...

You didn't actually CALL the functions and thus pass their return result to Promise.all().  Instead, you just passed function references to Promise.all().  Since Promise.all() is expecting an array of promises, but you passed an array of function references, it has nothing to do or wait for - it does not call the functions for you.

There are two issues with your code.

You don't return the fetch result in the processDoc function return await fetch.
You need to invoke the functions inside the array parameter of Promise.all to wait for these promises await Promise.all([processDoc1(), processDoc2()]).

let doc1Text = "";
let doc2Text = "";

const processDoc = async (fileInput) => {
    var input = document.getElementById(fileInput);
    
    return await fetch(urls.GetContractLanguageText, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: input.files[0]
    })
    .then(j => j.json())
    .then(x => x.ConvertedText);
}

const processDoc1 = async () => {
    $(selectors.fileProgress1).val(0);
    doc1Text = await processDoc(selectors.baseFile);
    $(selectors.fileProgress1).val(100);
};

const processDoc2 = async () =>  {
    $(selectors.fileProgress2).val(0);
    doc2Text = await processDoc(selectors.newFile);
    $(selectors.fileProgress2).val(100);
};

const processFiles = async () => {
    $(selectors.aiComparison).removeClass(selectors.hide);
    await Promise.all([processDoc1(), processDoc2()])
        .then(() => {
          console.log(doc1Text, doc2Text);
        });
}


Also use either return ….then(…), or await …; return …, but not both.
